# MySQL move part of a cell to another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following imported to TableA, Column 'Clothes' and Column 'Colours'

The problem is the import has put in the 'Clothes' column 'Jeans - Blue' and 'Jumper - Red' etc etc

Please could someone help me with a query to keep everything before the - in 'Clothes' and everything after the - into 'Colours' and removing the - altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps for this.

First, update the colors:

```
UPDATE yourTableA T
SET T.Colours = TRIM(SUBSTR(T.Clothes,INSTR(T.Clothes,'-') + 2));
```

Second, update the Clothes:

```
UPDATE yourTableA T
SET T.Clothes = TRIM(SUBSTR(T.Clothes,1,INSTR(T.clothes,'-')-1));
```

I've used [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) as my string swiss army knife here, and [`INSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) to locate the position of the - in between. You can do without [`TRIM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), but I usually use this in those cases to avoid unnecessary white spaces.

There surely are more direct ways to do it, but this'll work.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include a predicate (WHERE clause) that tests whether the delimiter is found within the column value. When the delimiter is not found within the string, INSTR returns a zero, and that can introduce an undesirable behavior with a SUBSTRING function. And when more than one delimiter occurs, this will "lose" the part between the first and last delimiters.

Comment: Aye, very true. This all depends a bit on the scale of his project. I just broke it down in two easy-to-understand `UPDATE`-statements in order to show how this issue can be tackled. Of course it has to be tested thoroughly and verified against all data he has in that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single `UPDATE` as follows:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET `Colours` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Clothes`, ' - ', -1),
    `Clothes` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Clothes`, ' - ', 1)
;
```

You can experiment with [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03090/1) I created from your data.

Here's the data I worked with:

CREATE TABLE TableA
    (`Clothes` varchar(20), `Colours` varchar(20))
;

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    (`Clothes`, `Colours`)
VALUES
    ('Jeans - Blue', NULL),
    ('Jumper - Red', NULL)
;
```

This the result of `SELECT * FROM TableA;` :

```
CLOTHES COLOURS
Jeans   Blue
Jumper  Red
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I have used that but for some reason, Colours and Clothes are now exactly the same, both saying 'Jeans - Blue' and 'Jumper - Red' etc etc

Comment: It might be good to note that the ORDER in which the new columns are assigned is important. (Once a new value gets assigned to the Clothes column in the statement, the previous value of Clothes is no longer available.) Also, it might be good to note the behavior when the string contains MORE THAN ONE occurrence of the delimiter.  (Including a predicate that tests for exactly one occurrence of the delimiter is good prevention... `WHERE LENGTH(Clothes)-LENGTH(REPLACE(Clothes,'-','')) = 1`

Comment: @MichaelCole - I added the data I worked with and the result I got. You can see it for yourself following the SQL Fiddle link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

The `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function is convenient, and the `TRIM` function can remove leading and trailing spaces. For example:

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.Clothes,'-',1)) AS Clothes
     , TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.Clothes,'-',-1)) AS Colours
  FROM TableA a
 WHERE LENGTH(a.Clothes)-LENGTH(REPLACE(a.Clothes,'-','')) = 1
```

(NOTE: the query above is returning the substring before the first '-' character, and is returning the substring after the last '-' character. So any values with more than one dash would lose the portion between the first and last dashes, consider e.g. 'A - B - C - D', the query above returns the A and returns the D, and loses everything else.

To handle this anomaly, the WHERE clause checks that the string contains a single occurrence of the '-' character.

Once you have a query you are happy with, you can turn that into an UPDATE statement, BUT be VERY careful about the order you assign new values to columns.  Unlike other relational databases, MySQL does not guarantee that a reference to an existing column within the statement will be the value of the column from the beginning of the statement... the only guarantee is that it will be the value that is currently assigned. So, the order that the columns is assigned is important!

```
UPDATE TableA a
   SET Colours = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.Clothes,'-',-1))
     , Clothes = TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.Clothes,'-',1))
 WHERE LENGTH(a.Clothes)-LENGTH(REPLACE(a.Clothes,'-','')) = 1
```

Note that if we were to assign the Clothes column before we assigned a value to the Colours column, the value we want assigned to Colours would be "lost".